# Continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that its zeros form a nowhere dense set of positive measure?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, roots

I know few facts,

- if $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $Z(f) \triangleq f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed,
- there are continuous functions whose zeros are nowhere dense,
- there are nowhere dense sets of positive measure.

From these facts, I cannot conclude that if $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and its zeros $Z(f)$ form a nowhere dense set, this set $Z(f)$ is of null measure. Can we prove that it is indeed the case, or exhibit a counter-example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer to the title question: Yes! There exists such a function. For example,  consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$$ where $A$ is the **fat cantor set** in $[0,1]$ and $B$ is any closed  singleton set $\{b\}$ where $b \notin A$. Then $f$ is continuous whose zero set is $A$, which is nowhere dense in $[0,1]$ of positive measure!

---

**Edit**: The function $x \mapsto d(x,A)$ alone works.

Comment: Thanks. Never heard about "fat" cantor set.

Comment: See [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.7110.pdf) paper .It explains what a  fat cantor set is

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant and simple!

Comment: Both of  you are very welcome!

Comment: What's wrong with $f(x)=d(x,A)$? Why do we have to divide by $d(x,A)+d(x,B)$?

Comment: @bof: Yes ! Its alone works and I agree. But the reason for giving this function is:  the reader will also remembering the another hidden fact "any  metric space is a normal space "